# sql difference in two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join

In sql server, I have two tables:

```
Tran_Ex

Transactions
```

They both have `customer_id` which is the key to join the tables.

I want to find the difference in WORKING DAYS of the `Date_Reported` (from transactions) from the `Date_Received` (from the Tran_ex). I would like an extra column with these figures:

eg

```
Date Reported | Date Received | Difference in days
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look for `DATEDIFF` function.

Comment: The datediff solutions look like a great start. But you said working days. This usually means you want to exclude weekends and holidays. This is where you want to use a calendar table in addition to datediff. You can read more about calendar tables here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DATEDIFF()](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/default.asp) function()

You can get **Working Day (Monday to Friday)** difference from this query, for bank holidays you need seperate logic.

```
Select Date_Reported, 
Date_Received ,
(DATEDIFF(dd, Date_Reported, Date_Received) + 1)
-(DATEDIFF(wk, Date_Reported, Date_Received) * 2)
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Date_Reported) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Date_Received) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 AS Working_days_Difference
from Tran_Ex as tx
inner join
Transactions as tr
on(tx.customer_id = tr.customer_id)
```

Modified the Query on suggestions based on @scsimon for not using shorthands.

```
SELECT Date_Reported, 
   Date_Received , 
   datediff(day,((CASE WHEN Datename(weekday, Date_Reported) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0  END ) - (CASE WHEN Datename(weekday, Date_Received ) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )),Datediff(day,(Datediff(week, Date_Reported, Date_Received ) * 2 ), 
   (Datediff(day, Date_Reported, Date_Received ) + 1 )))
   AS Working_days_Difference

    from Tran_Ex as tx
    inner join
    Transactions as tr
    on(tx.customer_id = tr.customer_id)
```

Comment: In your original answer you didn't use short hand, then you changed it. I would encourage you to *not* use shorthand with datetime formats. [Aaron has a good blog on this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations). Also, you need to be sure what their [DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) setting is for this to work

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion @scsimon, Added the query without shorthand

Comment: no problem @TanveerSinghBhatia but you missed the shorthand again. instead of `datediff(dd,` it would be `datediff(day,` and likewise for `wk` and `dw`. Have a gander at that article.

Comment: Thanks again @scsimon, Changed datepart shorthands also

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEDIFF()` function :

```
select t.Date_Reported, t1.Date_Received,
       datediff(day, t.Date_Reported, t1.Date_Received) [Difference in days]
from Tran_Ex tx
inner join Transactions t on t.customer_id  = tx.customer_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, will this take into consideration working days only (excluding weekends and bank holidays)

Comment: No this doesn't consider weekend or holidays of any kind. It is just the number of days. See my comment on your original question.